# C++ Using Keccak Library

Tags: c++, keccak, post-quantum-cryptography

Im working on my bachelor thesis and I have to test some post quantum algorithms. I downloaded them from NIST. But when I tried DAGS: https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-1/submissions/DAGS.zip and tried to "make" dags3 or dags5 I got this error:

encapsulation.o: In function `encapsulation':
encapsulation.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to`KangarooTwelve'
encapsulation.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `KangarooTwelve'
encapsulation.c:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to`KangarooTwelve'
encapsulation.c:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to `KangarooTwelve'
decapsulation.o: In function`decapsulation':
decapsulation.c:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `KangarooTwelve'
decapsulation.o:decapsulation.c:(.text+0x1bd): more undefined references to`KangarooTwelve' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'PQCgenKAT_kem' failed
make: *** [PQCgenKAT_kem] Error 1

I have keccak library installed and in this algorithm keccak library is included. Any ideas? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you follow the directions and download `git clone https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage` and then `make generic64/libkeccak.a` and copy the resulting library and headers to `/usr/local` as specified in the `README.md` file?

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Rankin , yes i tried everything I could possibly find. I tried following dags readme too but it didn't work.

Comment: Check the `encapsulation.c` source as well as the `keccak/KangarooTwelve` file and see if there wasn't a symbol change from, to, e.g. `Kangaroo-Twelve`, or `KangarooTwelve2`, etc... The errors are linker errors telling you it cannot find `KangarooTwelve`. It would be worth grepping the entire source (including the numerous macros in the `keccak` directory) for `roo` to see if something funny was done with one of the kangaroo names. That's the only things that makes sense at this point.

Comment: I'll have time after work to build it and if I find anything I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you, well there should not be any errors in code because this algorithm is submitted to: https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-1-submissions so someone had to run this code before successfully. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pursuant to the comments, I had time to look into the build tonight (also on Archlinux), I didn't experience any problems. Here are the detailed steps I used.

First the general kernel and gcc info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux valkyrie 4.19.4-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT 
Fri Nov 23 09:06:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20180831
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Cloning the KeccakCodePackage:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage
```

I usually try and and do an out-of-source build, especially with git repos (just habit from building TDE/KDE3), so I just create a `kbuild` and copy the source files over:

```
$ md kbuild
$ cp -a KeccakCodePackage/* kbuild/
$ cd kbuild
```

Now build the required static library per the Readme file and copy the library and headers to /usr/local/, e.g.:

```
$ make generic64/libkeccak.a

$ sudo cp -a bin/generic64/libkeccak.a /usr/local/lib
$ sudo cp -a bin/generic64/libkeccak.a.headers /usr/local/include
```

Now unzip and build DAGS `PQCgenKAT_kem`

```
$ cd ..
$ unzip DAGS.zip
$ cd DAGS/Optimized_Implementation/kem/dags5

$ make
gcc -c gf.c -o gf.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c poly.c -o poly.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c matrix.c -o matrix.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
matrix.c: In function ‘matrix_multiplication’:
matrix.c:13:16: warning: ‘res’ may be used uninitialized in this function 
                [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        return res;
                ^~~
matrix.c: In function ‘matrix_multiplicaion_subfield’:
matrix.c:59:16: warning: ‘Res’ may be used uninitialized in this function 
                [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
        return Res;
                ^~~
gcc -c fichier.c -o fichier.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c key_gen.c -o key_gen.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c encapsulation.c -o encapsulation.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c decapsulation.c -o decapsulation.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c util.c -o util.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c decoding.c -o decoding.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c kem.c -o kem.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c rng.c -o rng.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -c PQCgenKAT_kem.c -o PQCgenKAT_kem.o -march=native -mtune=native -c -Wall -I.
gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native gf.o poly.o matrix.o fichier.o key_gen.o
    encapsulation.o decapsulation.o util.o decoding.o kem.o rng.o PQCgenKAT_kem.o 
    -o PQCgenKAT_kem -L/usr/lib -L. -lssl -lcrypto -lkeccak
```

Finally run the resulting executable:

```
$ ./PQCgenKAT_kem
Starting iteration: 0
```

(all good, no clue what it does from there, but no errors and it is started fine...)

So, I'm not able to offer a "silver-bullet" of what went wrong with your build, but I can confirm the build, according to the various Readme files, proceeds as advertised and results in a working executable. Let me know if you have additional questions.