# There is a difficulty in running "nist round 3 classic mceliece"

Tags: c++, keccak

There is a difficulty in running "nist round 3 classic mceliece".
I'd like to run the classic mceliece submitted to Nist.
but when i run "make"

```
crypto_hash.h: 3:10: fatal error: libkeccak.a.heads/Simple FIPS202.h: No such file or directory exists
3 | #include <libkeccak.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h>
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:5: kat] Error 1".
```

I referred to the question [C++ Using Keccak Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605241/c-using-keccak-library).

So I downloaded it from "https://github.com/XKCP/XKCP" but it doesn't work.
(Probably the same as "https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage")

I think the name of libkeccak has been changed. (KXCP?)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and managed to solve it.

Your linked post helped me: [C++ Using Keccak Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605241/c-using-keccak-library?rq=1)

Then you need to change the include from libkeccak.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h to libXKCP.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h

After that, you also need to change one of the flags in compilation from -lkeccak to -lXKCP, this is in the file *build*