# NIST Round 3 Classic McEliece Missing Libkeccek.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, keccak, post-quantum-cryptography

I am attempting to build the KAT's for the round 3 submission for Classic McEliece, based off the reference implementation on this site:

https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/post-quantum-cryptography-standardization/round-3-submissions

When I try and build it, I get the error:
libkeccak.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h

I have attempted to build XKCP by cloning this repo: https://github.com/XKCP/XKCP
and running: make generic64/libXKCP.a

I can see that this builds, and I get a directory within the repo ./bin/generic64/libXKCP.a.headers

Has the name of this project changed since the round 3 submissions were released, or should I be looking for a different repository?

If this is correct, I still cannot build Classic McEliece, even if I change all references from libkeccak.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h to libXKCP.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h

Do I need to move this directory: ./bin/generic64/libXKCP.a.headers somewhere to allow gcc to find it? (I am on wsl)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it myself.
This question helped me: [C++ Using Keccak Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605241/c-using-keccak-library?rq=1)

I had to clone those repos to the correct spot.

Then you need to change the include from libkeccak.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h to libXKCP.a.headers/SimpleFIPS202.h , as I guessed.

After that, you also need to change one of the flags in compilation from -lkeccak to -lXKCP (I couldnt find a reference anywhere, so this was a guess, but it worked.)